# python for loop and if else

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to print x if x % 2 == 0 and if it is not, print y.
It did not work for me

```
range = list(range(1, 5))
print(x for x, y in enumerate(range) if(x % 2 == 0) else y)
```

Comment: I think you mean `(x if x%2==0 else y for (x, y) in enumerate(range))`, but printing a generator expression is not going to show anything very useful.

Comment: "It did not work for me" ... why? What did you expect? What happened? What is wrong?

Comment: dont use built ins as variable names - you shadow the `range()` function by doing `range = list(range(1,5))`

Comment: Please work through a tutorial on list comprehensions.  You need to follow the syntax given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the for loop at the end like this:

```
range = list(range(1, 5))
print(x if x % 2 == 0 else y for x,y in enumerate(range))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update the expression:

```
>>> range = list(range(1, 5))
>>> myIter = (( x if (x % 2 == 0) else y) for (x, y) in enumerate(range) )
>>> print(list(myIter))
[0,2,2,4]
```